# Change primefaces dialog size on client side

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I change the size of a primefaces dialog with:

```
dialog.css('width', '650px');
```

The dialog is getting bigger but its content is not resized. When I change the size of the dialog on a corner with the mouse, its content is updated (div with ui-resizable-handle css class).
So probably I have to call another javascript method to emulate the changing how it was done with the mouse?
Unfortunately I haven't found the method. Somebody has done this already?

Regards
Oliver

Comment: Where did the `dialog` variable come from?

Comment: Answer depends on PF version. Please remember to always mention the impls/versions in every single question involving external APIs/libraries.

Comment: `dialog` variable was retrieved with jquery `$('dialogId')`. I am using JSF 2.2.10 and Primefaces 5.1.18.

Comment: why don't you are using width attribute of p:dialog ?

Comment: If I use the width and height attributes I have to update the dialog which closes it. When I open it again I have to restore entered but not submitted data entered by the user. This leads to problems if validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

`dialog.trigger('resize');` does it.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not bubble to the inner components.